# AWS SES email delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am encountering the following problem here is my scenario; I have a VPC with two private subnets and one public subnet. Inside the public subnet I have a NAT instance to give outbound internet access to the private subnets. Inside the private subnets I have lambda functions that send time sensitive emails over SES. The problem is that each time an email is sent I receive it 4 minutes later. But here is the thing, the time on the email is the time that the email was requested. What I mean is that if I requested the email at 10:00 AM I will received it at 10:04 AM but the email says that it was delivered at 10:00 AM.

Here are some of the headers:

```
Received: by 2002:a02:8801:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r1csp3536638jai;
    Mon, 21 Sep 2020 **08:01:35** -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 2002:a0c:8f02:: with SMTP id z2mr280955qvd.21.1600700255279;
    Mon, 21 Sep 2020 **07:57:35** -0700 (PDT)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please add to your question the complete message headers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton hey, what do you mean?

Comment: Email headers include the history of services that relayed it: SES, your mail provider, and possibly mail security services.  Please provide those headers. If you don't know how in your mail client, ask Super User or other user-focused forums.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added two of the headers that show the delay

Comment: Those are not complete, though.

Answer (score 2):

Email is *not meant and designed for “time sensitive” messages*, definitely not for those where 4 minutes delay matters.

The reason for the delay could be for example [Greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)) on the destination server, DNS issues, waiting for some some service timeout, etc.

If you need to send time sensitive messages use an appropriate channel, where you can check whether and when the message was delivered (and read) and escalate to some other channel if not. For example SMS (e.g. through [Message Media](https://messagemedia.com)), push messages (e.g. [Pushover service](https://pushover.net/), and escalate to automated voice calls (e.g. [Twilio](https://twilio.com)). Email is not the right channel for time sensitive messages.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hey, how about forgot password emails? I give the user 1 minute to request another email but I don't think making the user wait 4 minutes will be a good user experience. Btw thank you for your answer.

Comment: Jamie, if you want help you need to provide the information above that Michael requested. And like MLu says, you can't rely on email delivering within a given amount of time. I agree that 4 minutes is higher than average and you should be able to reduce that down, but you can't count it delivering immediately. Giving a user 1 minute to do something isn't doing to work for everyone. Maybe give them 24 hours.

Comment: Indeed. Email may take _hours_ or (rarely) _days_ to arrive. I've lost count of the number of times I was sent a password reset email and the link had already expired before the email arrived.

Comment: I ran a service for a little while where our customer experience relied heavily on emails arriving quickly. It was not hard for us to to ensure that emails delivered in seconds. Sending SES->Gmail was the fastest for us, if there are regular delays those were usually issues with the quality of the server or service receiving the email. The long tail of delays certainly happens, and we've seen those as well, but the idea that email is not designed for speed seems a little detached from modern expectations.